jboss tools and wtp not doing auto-complete
I have a fresh eclipse, just downloaded. I then added jboss and wtp to the eclipse. I then imported an existing JSF project and I create a new very simple JSF project with backing bean and one xhtml file.
In either jboss or wtp editors, I can't get any type of auto-complete to work. The ctrl-click will take me to the class and method so I can see it's resolving things, but autocomplete is always blank.
Is there a way to get that to work? I've tried changing the extensions to .jsp, .jsf, nothing seems to work.
Thank you!

Do you have code to show, and why two projects were mentioned?

Are there any types of file / languages for which Eclipse auto-complete or intellisense does work on your machine?
